# numpy masked assignment through advanced indexing

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So I am learning numpy and in this book there is a question that tells me to create three arrays Z, M, and C.
In my Z array I'm suppose to create a (4,5) dimensional array and my M array is a boolean mask array which is the same size (4,5) but is True where
 `M = abs(Z) < 2`
My C array is also the same size but just holds complex numbers in it
`C = np.full(Z.shape, (-0.4 + 0.6j), dtype=complex)`

Now my three arrays are the following

```
[[2.23606798 1.41421356 1.         1.41421356 2.23606798]
 [2.02758751 1.05409255 0.33333333 1.05409255 2.02758751]
 [2.02758751 1.05409255 0.33333333 1.05409255 2.02758751]
 [2.23606798 1.41421356 1.         1.41421356 2.23606798]]

[[False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True  True  True False]
 [False  True  True  True False]]

[[-0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j]
 [-0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j]
 [-0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j]
 [-0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j -0.4+0.6j]]
```

**Changed typo from multiply C to add C**

Now here's my question. I am suppose to multiply each element in my Z array by themselves and then add them by C where all the M array elements are True
So I would use `Z[M]`
But when I try to multiply it, since the Z array changes to a 1 dimensional array, I'm not sure how to go about it. I need my array shape to be the same, I just want to augment the Z elements where the M elements are true without changing the dimensions of the Z array

Correct final output for Z array should be this from the back of the book

```
[[-2.        -1.j         -0.4       +2.6j        -1.4       +0.6j
  -0.4       -1.4j         2.        -1.j        ]
 [-2.        -0.33333333j  0.48888889+1.26666667j -0.51111111+0.6j
   0.48888889-0.06666667j  2.        -0.33333333j]
 [-2.        +0.33333333j  0.48888889-0.06666667j -0.51111111+0.6j
   0.48888889+1.26666667j  2.        +0.33333333j]
 [-2.        +1.j         -0.4       -1.4j        -1.4       +0.6j
  -0.4       +2.6j         2.        +1.j        ]]
```

Comment: Why would Z change to a 1D array?

Comment: When Z[M] runs, it finds all of the values and then puts them into a new 1D array. I might be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html sounds like the operation you're wanting to use - multiplying each element, rather than changing anything?

Comment: What values should be ised for the locations where M==False?

Comment: The values where False should just stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your masked array has to be 1-D, because in a general mask, there might be no rectangular shaped True values. To make a multiplication, simply use mask on every element of your masked calculation:

```
Z[M]*Z[M]*C[M]
```

output:

```
[-0.8       +1.2j        -0.4       +0.6j        -0.8       +1.2j
 -0.44444444+0.66666666j -0.04444444+0.06666667j -0.44444444+0.66666666j
 -0.44444444+0.66666666j -0.04444444+0.06666667j -0.44444444+0.66666666j
 -0.8       +1.2j        -0.4       +0.6j        -0.8       +1.2j       ]
```

Another approach is to use MaskedArrays. This will preserve the shape and only mask the False elements:

```
Z = np.ma.MaskedArray(Z,M)
C = np.ma.MaskedArray(C,M)
Z*Z*C
```

output:

```
[[(-2.0000000044725126+3.000000006708768j) -- -- -- (-2.0000000044725126+3.000000006708768j)]
 [(-1.6444444442832002+2.4666666664248003j) -- -- -- (-1.6444444442832002+2.4666666664248003j)]
 [(-1.6444444442832002+2.4666666664248003j) -- -- -- (-1.6444444442832002+2.4666666664248003j)]
 [(-2.0000000044725126+3.000000006708768j) -- -- -- (-2.0000000044725126+3.000000006708768j)]]
```

**EDIT**: based on OP comment, if you want to change values of `Z` only where `M` is `True`:

```
Z = Z.astype(complex)
Z[M] = Z[M]*Z[M]*C[M]
```

output:

```
print(Z)
[[ 2.23606798+0.j         -0.8       +1.2j        -0.4       +0.6j        -0.8       +1.2j         2.23606798+0.j]
 [ 2.02758751+0.j         -0.44444444+0.66666666j -0.04444444+0.06666667j        -0.44444444+0.66666666j  2.02758751+0.j]
 [ 2.02758751+0.j         -0.44444444+0.66666666j -0.04444444+0.06666667j        -0.44444444+0.66666666j  2.02758751+0.j]
 [ 2.23606798+0.j         -0.8       +1.2j        -0.4       +0.6j        -0.8       +1.2j         2.23606798+0.j]]
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, now I'm just curious how I would put it back into a (4,5) format with the elements that have been changing into the correct spot.

Comment: @JohnBaltimore Depends how you would want the masked elements to be. I understand that you want True elements to be `Z*Z*C`, but what would you like to put False elements as? Also, please checkout my addition to post about `MaskedArray`s. That might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I just saw your addition, with the False elements I want them to just stay the same. I do not want to convert them to 0's or remove them

Comment: @JohnBaltimore _stay the same_ from what? I tried to understand your posted output, but could not figure out what False elements' values are coming from. Maybe you can elaborate on that. Thank you.

Comment: So I want to change my Z array. Using the M mask, wherever it is True, I want to change the Z elements, wherever M is False, I do not want to change them, I want the Z elements to stay the same there. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JohnBaltimore Please checkout the addition to the post according to your comment. Although your comment will not result in the output you posted in the question. Feel free to accept the answer if it resolves the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this: `z * z * c * m`

In `m`, all the False values are represented as zero, and all the True values are represented as one.  You can see this by `m * 1`

Comment: So would I say``` Z[M] = Z * Z * C * M``` ? I can try that out, I just keep getting wrong dimension errors

Answer (score 0):

To apply an operation to "*where all the M array elements are True*", you can literally use "where":

```
np.where(M, Z * Z * C, Z)
```

Think of it as `if M then Z * Z * C else Z` on steroids.

Comment: So from the documentation, M is the condition, Z * Z * C is what I want to change, and Z is where I want to change it to?

Comment: Z\*Z\*C are the "new" values (for M==True), Z are the "old" values (for Z==False). Unless you want something else for M==False (it is not clear from your question).

Comment: Ah this makes sense, thanks for helping out even though I can be a little bit slow sometimes. I added what the correct output should be from the back of the book to my main question

Answer (score 0):

As your exercise is telling you to use masks, you can do something like this:

```
Z = 3j*np.random.rand(4,5) #Create array
M = abs(Z) < 2  #Create mask
C = np.full(Z.shape, (-0.4 + 0.6j), dtype=complex) #Create complex
```

An then the operation you want to do:

```
Z[M] = Z[M]*Z[M]+C[M]
```

Look that I am using the mask in the right-hand side as well as in the left-hand side. So I am telling numpy something like:
"To the indices in Z, signaled by this mask, assign the products of the elements of Z,Z and C, all of which are signaled by the same mask" or something of the sort.

Comment: Not only this is a duplicate of another posted answer, but also this solution is converting complex to real numbers, since `Z` is of real number format.

Comment: The difference in posting time between your edited answer and mine was minimal, I didn't see your answer. Further, I corrected my example before seeing your answer and your comment. Don't worry, nobody is here to take your points away.

Comment: It happens a lot that two people want to post almost same time. I personally remove my answer if someone posts the exact same answer a minute before it. It is about keeping the site clean and most readable to the readers. If an answer is merely a copy, there is really no point in posting it. Nobody is getting an award for points here. Having that said, this answer lacks `dtype` conversion and keeping it might be useful to another reader.